# Is there any comprehensive ttk styling documentation out there

Tags: tkinter, styles, ttk

I'm working with ttk widgets and want to use the styling options. While I can find documentation about various dynamic states and various options, it is always hard to find out which option does what.
Take e.g. the Combobox. There are lots of styling options like

```
-arrowcolor color
-arrowsize amount
-background color
-bordercolor color
-darkcolor color
-focusfill color
-foreground color
-fieldbackground color

Can only be changed when using non-native and non-graphical themes.
-insertcolor color
-insertwidth amount
-lightcolor color
-padding padding
-placeholderforeground color
-postoffset padding
-selectbackground color  (Text entry select background)
-selectforeground color  (Text entry select foreground)
```

but for many items it's hard to tell, what they mean and I can't find any docs about that. I can only try out, which can be quite hard with complex widgets as a combo-box, which not only has various elements, but also quite some dynamic states.

I'm running mad, because I only can find pages, which either show only very simplified examples or just name the options and don't tell what they are for (like e.g. https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.7/TkCmd/ttk_combobox.html, which the above list is from and looks like the definitive source of information of that kind, but it is so limited...)

Is there really no decent doc about ttk styling out there?

Comment: While not comprehensive, this gives a pretty decent overview: https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/styles.html

Answer (score 1):

For an in-depth guide to themes, the official python documentation suggests looking at the [Tcl’2004 conference presentation](http://tktable.sourceforge.net/tile/tile-tcl2004.pdf).

> Tcl’2004 conference presentation This document explains how the theme
> engine works

The presentation link leads to a PDF file which contains a well and deep description of the options including those mentioned in the OP.

The official python documentation for the same is [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.ttk.html#ttk-styling).

[This](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/List+of+ttk+Themes) and [this](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/ttk-layouts.html) were some other useful resources that I could find.

Comment: Thanks Bryan and typedecker for sharing these links (which I unfortunately had visited most of them already and not found what I'm looking for). All these documents only explain the concept or at most a few styling options, but I didn't find any document that really explains (e.g. with the help of an image of the widget), what all the options are for. I tried to figure out for the Combobox widget, which took me far more than an hour and I still don't know, how e.g. the background of the text in the Combobox can be styled when it's selected - maybe it can't...

Comment: There is one more super useful resource once called effbot which I personally used to learn tkinter, but has been down now for a few years, but a restoration project of sorts for it has been on the way [here](https://dafarry.github.io/tkinterbook/), maybe this will be helpful.

Comment: If this is indeed helpful, I will also include it in the main answer for future visitors.

Comment: Also, within effbot's archive in a way as mentioned above, perhaps the [widget styling](https://dafarry.github.io/tkinterbook/tkinter-widget-styling.htm) part is what you might be interested in having a look at.

Comment: Thanks a lot for sharing - it is definitely a very nice tkinter resource. Unfortunately it handles only basic tkinter widgets - no ttk; nevertheless a very nice resource indeed!

Comment: Yes, I think the original one did have some links for ttk but it got taken down unfortunately as the owner died, They are slowly shifting the information to this archive, so it might eventually be there.

Comment: Oh, sorry to hear that! Well, there are bigger things on this world than missing documentaton...

Comment: Definitely before it went down, it was one of the best resources to learn tkinter and many posts on this site linked to it as well.